# bonsai.io elasticsearch and field type

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to use bonsai.io elasticsearch stack.
I'm mapping a field type like "float" but the mapped type into the index is STRING and is not editable. This is a problem of the trial versione ?

Thk